# How to add new panels before and after clicked panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Report designer detail band contains Add band button which shoud add new panels immediately before and after detail panel.

```
$parentpanel = $this.parents(".designer-panel:first");
```

is used to find parent panel and .prepend() / append() to add new panels.

Panels are added as Detail panel child elements.
How to add panels before and after Detail panel in same DOM level like group header and footer panels in sample html.

Elements should probably added to `$parentpanel.parent()` element list before and after `$parentpanel` element.

Is there some selector or append command in jQuery for this ?

```js
$(function() {

  var startpos,
    selected = $([]),
    offset = {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    };

  $('#designer-detail-addband').on('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $parentpanel = $this.parents(".designer-panel:first");

    $parentpanel.prepend('<div class="panel designer-panel">' +
      '<div class="panel-body designer-panel-body" style="height:1px">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="bg-warning">' +
      '<div class="panel-footer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up">' +
      '</i> Group heade {0}: <span id="band{0}_expr" contenteditable="true">"groupexpression"</span>' +
      '</div></div></div>');

    $parentpanel.append('<div class="panel designer-panel">' +
      '<div class="panel-body designer-panel-body" style="height:1px"></div>' +
      '<div class="bg-warning">' +
      '<div class="panel-footer"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up">' +
      '</i> Group footer {0}' +
      '</div></div></div>');

  });

  $(".designer-panel-body").droppable({
    accept: ".designer-field"
  });

  $(".designer-field").draggable({
    start: function(event, ui) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.hasClass("ui-selected")) {
        selected = $(".ui-selected").each(function() {
          var el = $(this);
          el.data("offset", el.offset());
        });
      } else {
        selected = $([]);
        $(".designer-field").removeClass("ui-selected");
      }
      offset = $this.offset();
    },

    drag: function(event, ui) {
      // drag all selected elements simultaneously
      var dt = ui.position.top - offset.top,
        dl = ui.position.left - offset.left;
      selected.not(this).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var elOffset = $this.data("offset");
        $this.css({
          top: elOffset.top + dt,
          left: elOffset.left + dl
        });
      });
    }
  });

  $(".panel-resizable").resizable({
    minWidth: "100%",
    maxWidth: "100%",
    minHeight: 1
  });
})
```

```css
.panel-resizable {
  min-height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.designer-field {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.designer-panel-body {
  min-height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.panel-footer {
  padding: 0;
}
.designer-panel,
.panel-body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='panel designer-panel'>
    <div class='panel-body designer-panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:2cm'>

      <div class='designer-field' style='left:5px;top:6px;width:180px'>field 1 in group 1 header</div>

      <div class='designer-field' style='left:54px;top :36px;width:160px'>field 2 in group 1 header</div>
    </div>

    <div class='panel-footer'>Group 1 Header</div>
  </div>

  <div class='panel designer-panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:1cm'>
      <div class='designer-field' style='left:24px;top:2px;width:140px'>field in detail group</div>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-primary'>Detail <a role="button" id="designer-detail-addband"> Add group</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='panel'>
    <div class='panel-body panel-resizable' style='height:1cm'>

      <div class='designer-field' style='left:44px;top:2px;width:140px'>field in group 1 footer</div>
    </div>
    <div class='panel-footer panel-warning'>Group 1 Footer</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery's [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/), [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) functions. Or [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/), [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

Also you can use

```
$this.closest(".designer-panel");
```

instead of

```
$this.parents(".designer-panel:first");
```

See [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. how to make headers sortable in this code ? I posted it in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333881/how-to-make-header-panels-sortable